# Side Navigation bar within a page, setting active to the <a> tag if it is on the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am trying to add a side nav bar within one of my pages that would go to other pages. I currently have the sidebar working and am wondering if it would be possible to add an active class that corresponds to whichever page you are currently on, and I cannot seem to get the active attribute added to the class.

My side nav HTML code is in a jspf file and is included in the main jsp.

Here is the Side Nav HTML code:

```js
$(function() {
  setActive();
});

function setActive() {
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
  $('.sideNav > ul > li > a[href="' + pathname + '"]').addClass('active');
  alert(pathname);
}
```

```css
.sideNav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
}

.sideNav a:active {
  color: #4080ff;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sideNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a style="font-size: 27px; color: #4080ff;">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">Why Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="customers">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a href="documents">Documents</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My url for Customers page looks like this:

> /BedrockWeb/customers

I guess I need help filtering the variable pathname to just get the end part of the url after the slash so that it matches with each href.

Comment: do you have access to the pages customers, documents and about...? I mean can you change the code there?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri Yes, I'm using the jspf include so that way I do not have to copy and paste the side nav HTML piece in each page.

Comment: the problem is that it doesnt add the class?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Yes sorry, it is not adding the active class

Comment: ok just do pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/')[window.location.pathname.split('/').length-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a jQuery each loop to look at the href for each link in the nav and added the 'active' class if the href matches the pathname.

```js
function setActive() {
  let pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
  // for testing lets set pathname = documents
  pathname = 'documents';
  
  $( '.sideNav > ul > li > a' ).each( function() {
    if ( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) == pathname ) {
      $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
    }
  });

}

setActive();
```

```css
.sideNav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
}

.sideNav a.active {
  color: #4080ff;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sideNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a style="font-size: 27px; color: #4080ff;">Customers</a</li>
    <li><a href="about">Why Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="customers">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a href="documents">Documents</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```